# Control ELB by Traffic load

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, autoscaling

We recently used Amazon AWS.
Now our application is on the cloud. And we configured ELB with Auto Scalling and it works fine.
We need to modify the ELB and control how it works. I checked all the configuration and couldn't do it.

1. How could we customize the traffic distributation over the instances?
2. If it's not possible to do with ELB, is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELB distributes requests evenly amongst the healthy availability zones, then evenly amongst the instances in that zone. You can't configure this further. You'll want to make sure you don't do something like 3 instances in us-west-2a and one in us-west-2b, as the one in 2b would receive 3x the traffic as each of the 2a instances.

If you want load balancing based on something like instance load, you'll need to build your own solution in AWS with something like HAProxy.